# "C" i couldnt understand how i can add two matrises

Tags: c

I'm a begginer about c and i need help about it please help

```
{
    int matris[2][2];

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("Sayi giriniz: "); scanf("%d",&matris[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",matris[i][j]);
        }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For us to help you, you need to ask a *concrete, answerable* question, and show us what you have tried so far to resolve it. As it stands, the question is likely to get closed and attract negative votes.

Comment: Let A, B matrixes, A + B = C. Where c_i = a_i + b_i.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Create a second array and read input to there to have two matrices represented. Create a third array to accomodate the result.

Comment: so this code goes true for this?

Comment: `j<4` --> `j<2`, `i<3` --> `j<2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what your question is, but I can definately show you how to add two matricies of the same length elementwise, if that's what you're looking for.

```
#include <stdio>;

int main()
{
    //this part is declaring the two arrays you want to add,
    //and the array you want to store the result in.
    int arrayA[3];
    int arrayB[3];
    int result[3];

    //this part is just initializing the data in the array
    arrayA[0] = 1;
    arrayA[1] = 2;
    arrayA[2] = 3;
    arrayB[0] = 5;
    arrayB[1] = 6;
    arrayB[2] = 7;

    //loops from 0 to 2, and adds the nth element of arrayA and
    // arrayB to store in result
    for(int n =0; n < 3; n++)
    {
        result[n] = arrayA[n] + arrayB[n];
    }

    //at this point, result is the addition of your arrays.
    //You can print it, or whatever it is you wanted to do with it.

    return 0;
}
```

There are many different things that could be 'adding matricies', but this is one of them.

However, the code you submitted looks like you're trying to store numbers from the keyboard into a 2D array. You're on the right track there, but on your first nested for loop your inner loop goes too far, so it's going outside of the array bounds. Try more liek this:

```
int matris[2][2];

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    //you had j<4 here. That will put you in invalid memory!
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        printf("Sayi giriniz: "); scanf("%d",&matris[i][j]);
    }
}

//you had i<3 here. That will also put you in invalid memory.
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",matris[i][j]);
    }
        printf("\n");
}
```

I hope I've addressed whatever question you were going for.

İyi şanslar!

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, you need to realize that programming is nothing more than problem-solving, well there is the bit about expressing the answer in a programming language.

1. Doing matrix addition -- how do you do it, how would a mathematician define it?  Arnaldo has given you the answer to this, $A + B = C$ where $c_{ij}  = a_{ij} + b_{ij}$.  So already, this starts to set some restrictions on the two matrices that your are working with, notably they have to have the same number of rows and columns.
2. Representation of matrices -- ok, now that you know how to add to matrices, you need to figure out how you are going to represent a matrix in your program.  Computer memory is a one-dimensional array of storage units, so we need to map our two dimensional structure onto this one-dimensional array.  There are two ways of doing this.  The first is *row major* which means that we write the first row to memory, then the second row and so on.  The second is *column major* which means that we write the first column to memory and then the second row.

   ```
   Consider the following 2x3 matrix:

       | a b c |
       | d e f | 

    in row-major form, it would be laid out in memory as:

     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | a | b | c | d | e | f |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+

    and in column-major form, in would be laid out in memory as:

     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | a | d | b | e | c | f |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
   ```
3. Remember that computer science is zero based, so where a mathematician would designate the first element in the first row as a_{11}, we will be using zero based indicies so we will designate it as a_{00}.
4. Most modern program languages use row-major form to store two dimensional arrays (or in this discussion matrices).  So what you might ask?  Well, because we are mapping a two dimensional array to a one dimensional array, and all we really know about the one dimensional array is its starting point in memory, we need to be able to change the pair (row, col) into a single index.  You should convince yourself that the following equation is correct, assuming that nRow and nCol are the number of rows and columns in the matrix.

   ```
   index = nCol * row + col
   ```
5. So, now write some code to add to matrices together.  In pseudo-code form this would be:

   ```
   A <-- read in first n-by-m matrix
   B <-- read in second n-by-m matrix
   C <-- initialize a n-by-m matrix to all zero elements.

   for(r = 0; r < nRow; r++)
       for(c = 0; c < nCol; c++)
            C[r][c] = A[r][c] + B[r][c]

   print C
   ```
6. It is an implementation detail to decide if you want to use fix sized matrices, *i.e.* 'A[2][2]', or potentially use a dynamically allocated matrix, *i.e.* 'A = malloc(nRow * nCol * sizeof(int));' (assuming we are storing integers).  This will determine exactly how the addition line in the above pseudo-code would be written.

Hope this helps, and kinda show you how to approach problems like this.

Don't be afraid to ask additional questions if you get stuck on attempting the implementation.

Best of Luck,
T